# General recursion to tail-recursion

Tags: recursion, tail-call, lambda-calculus

Is it theoretically possible to transform every kind of general-recursion into tail-recursion? Are they equivalent for example from a lambda-calculus point of view? That's a debate between me and an acquaintance.

My view is that it's not possible everytime. For example if you have a function which calls itself recursively twice or three times, then you can't make all the recursive calls into tail-calls, right? Or is there always a way to reduce the number of recursive calls to one single recursive call?

Answer (score 6):

You should be able to do it using [continuation passing style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

In CPS, each function takes an explicit continuation function which represents the rest of the computation. Instead of returning a value directly, a function in CPS passes the result to the continuation instead.

For example if you had the following `Tree` data type:

```
type Tree = Empty | Node of Tree * int * Tree
```

and you wanted to sum the values, you could write function to sum the left and right subtrees in turn:

```
let rec sum_cps t f = 
    match t with
        | Empty -> f 0
        | Node(l, v, r) -> sum_cps l (fun lv ->
            sum_cps r (fun rv -> f (lv + v + rv)))

let sumT t = sum_cps t (fun i -> i)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do that transformation using [Continuation Passing Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation-passing_style).

Read for instance [A.Appel *Compiling with Continuations* book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052103311X)

Intuitively, you replace -after [CPS transformation](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?CpsTransformation)- (nearly) each call frame of the [call stack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) with a heap-allocated [continuation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation) frame (or "closure" when viewing continuations as functions). (so you might not win much: the avoided stack frames are replaced by [garbage collected](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29) continuation frames).

See also Appel's old paper: [garbage collection can be faster than stack allocation](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=31085)

<sup>(which might be less true today, perhaps because of [cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_%28computing%29) issues)</sup>

Comment: Oh course the downside is that you build lots and lots of closures (the continuations). It's not a good way to improve performance or memory use.